# how to compare two images face and if both of the same person show messagebox "same person". how can i code it using emguCV in c#.

Tags: emgucv

I am working on a programme in which user upload its own image in picturebox1 on upload button as trainer image, and then load another image in picturebox2 using button2 from D Drive. 
My question is how to compare both images face and if both of the same person show messagebox"same person". how can i code it using emguCV in c#.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial question and I don’t think there is a function CompareFaces(mat face1, mat face2) that you could use.
What you should try is reading up on:
1.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/product/cognitive-toolkit/ 
2.  https://www.tensorflow.org/
or other deep learning tool. 
This is something that will take you weeks to get to work and probably not get to work as good as you would expect!